# Keeping python sockets alive in event of connection loss

Tags: python, sockets, networking, connection

I'm trying to make a socket connection that will stay alive so that in event of connection loss. So basically I want to keep the server always open (also the client preferably) and restart the client after the connection is lost. But if one end shuts down both ends shut down. I simulated this by having both ends on the same computer `"localhost"` and just clicking the X button. Could this be the source of my problems?

Anyway my connection code
`m.connect(("localhost", 5000))`
is in a `if` and `try` and `while` e.g.

`while True:
    if tryconnection:
        #Error handeling
        try:
            m.connect(("localhost", 5000))
            init = True
            tryconnection = False
        except socket.error:
            init = False
            tryconnection = True`

And at the end of my code I just a `m.send("example")` when I press a button and if that returns an error the code of trying to connect to `"localhost"` starts again. And the server is a pretty generic server setup with a `while` loop around the `x.accept()`. So how do keep them both alive when the connection closes so they can reconnect when it opens again. Or is my code alright and its just by simulating on the same computer is messing with it?

Comment: TCP can't "keep the connection alive" - so there are at least two options: 1. use UDP, which is connectionless, and layer on top of that all needed layers to make the transfer of data reliable and flow-controlled (i.e. replicate quite a lot of the TCP stack :-o, or 2) continue using TCP but add a layer on top of it so that when the client reconnects the client gives some client-specific information (a token/cookie) to the server which allows the server to resume a previous connection. This is the way your browser can resume a web session with a server, using a cookie.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how I can add layers. I'm relatively new. Thanks

Comment: When the client connects it could automatically send a message saying 'here's my token which is this old' or 'no token' if client doesn't have one saved. At the server, for a new TCP connection wait for the token info and validate the token (e.g. does the server have a record of it? is it not-too-old? had the user logged off?) and handle appropriately. e.g. if client had logged off then user needs to re-authenticate. If not logged off an last connection was recent then resume the session. This is *exactly* how a website remembers users and retains shopping basket using cookies in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming we're dealing with TCP here since you use the word "connection".

It all depend by what you mean by "connection loss".

If by connection loss you mean that the data exchanges between the server and the client may be suspended/irresponsive (important: I did not say "closed" here) for a long among of time, seconds or minutes, then there's not much you can do about it and it's fine like that because the TCP protocol have been carefully designed to handle such situations gracefully. The timeout before deciding one or the other side is definitely down, give up, and close the connection is veeeery long (minutes). Example of such situation: the client is your smartphone, connected to some server on the web, and you enter a long tunnel.

But when you say: "But if one end shuts down both ends shut down. I simulated this by having both ends on the same computer localhost and just clicking the X button", what you are doing is actually *closing* the connections.

- If you abruptly terminate the server: the TCP/IP implementation of your operating system will know that there's not any more a process listening on port 5000, and will cleanly close all connections to that port. In doing so a few TCP segments exchange will occur with the client(s) side (it's a TCP 4-way tear down or a reset), and all clients will be disconected. It is important to understand that this is done at the TCP/IP implementation level, that's to say your operating system.
- If you abruptly terminate a client, accordingly, the TCP/IP implementation of your operating system will cleanly close the connection from it's port Y to your server port 5000.
- In both cases/side, at the network level, that would be the same as if you explicitly (not abruptly) closed the connection in your code.

...and once closed, there's *no way* you can possibly re-establish those connections as they were before. You have to establish new connections.

If you want to establish these new connections *and get the application logic to the state it was before*, now that's another topic. TCP alone can't help you here. You need a higher level protocol, maybe your own, to implement stateful client/server application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to the programming language, in this case python. The oeprating system (Windows or linux), has the final word regarding the resilience degree of the socket.